# Fill blank cells of a pandas dataframe column by matching with another datafame column is not working

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas dataframe, lets call it `df1` that looks like this (the follow is just a sample to give an idea of the dataframe):

| Ac | Tp | Id | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF | 100 | 200 | 45 |
| Asset | FC |  | 52 | 48 | 15 |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT | 45 | 58 | 15 |
| Tax | Other |  | 48 | 45 | 78 |

And I want to fill the blank spaces using a in the `'Id'` column using the next auxiliar dataframe, lets call it `df2` (again, this is just a sample):

| Ac | Tp | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT |
| Asset | FC | IQ_AST |
| Income | BAL | IQ_INC |
| Tax | Other | IQ_TAX |
| Invest | FC | IQ_INV |

To get `df1` dataframe, looking like this:

| Ac | Tp | Id | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF | 100 | 200 | 45 |
| Asset | FC | IQ_AST | 52 | 48 | 15 |
| Debt | P&G | IQ_DEBT | 45 | 58 | 15 |
| Tax | Other | IQ_TAX | 48 | 45 | 78 |

I tried using this line of code:

```
ac_typ = ['Ac', 'Tp']
df1['Id'] = df1[ac_typ].merge(df2[[*ac_typ,'Id']])['Id']
```

But it doesn't work because it actually don´t search the Ac name of the blank value of the Id column in df2 dataframe but just fill it with the next available, like that:

| Ac | Tp | Id | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Efecty | FC | IQ_EF | 100 | 200 | 45 |
| Asset | FC | IQ_DEBT | 52 | 48 | 15 |
| Debt | P&G | NaN | 45 | 58 | 15 |
| Tax | Other | NaN | 48 | 45 | 78 |

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

You code should work, ensure to perform a left-merge in case you have missing values:

```
ac_typ = ['Ac', 'Tp']
df1['Id'] = df1[ac_typ].merge(df2[[*ac_typ,'Id']], how='left')['Id']
```

If you want to keep the original `df1['Id']` values, even if they would differ from the merge result:

```
df1.loc[df1['ID'].isna(), 'Id'] = df1[ac_typ].merge(df2[[*ac_typ,'Id']], how='left')['Id']
```

Output:

```
       Ac     Tp       Id  2020  2021  2022
0  Efecty     FC    IQ_EF   100   200    45
1   Asset     FC   IQ_AST    52    48    15
2    Debt    P&G  IQ_DEBT    45    58    15
3     Tax  Other   IQ_TAX    48    45    78
```